# Why don't play animation when run toggleClass?

Tags: jquery

I use this code for toggleClass the show and hide class .This worked but not true .In this case 1 second wait and then run toggleclass with out animation.

```
$(function () {
    $("#open_search").click(function () {
        $("#search").toggleClass("show",1000);
        $("#open_search").toggleClass("hide",1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use:

    $('#search').show();
    $('#open_search').hide();

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: You don't want `toggleClass()`, but rather `toggle()`. Try:

```
$("#search").toggle();
```

Comment: Are you sure? This don't  work for me  .see this :http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Anyway, if you just want to show/hide stuff, I would suggest using either toggle() or show() and hide() since these are easier to setup than toggleClass().

Comment: I use   $("#search").show(1000);
        $("#open_search").hide( 1000);  ........ and solved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use toggle() instead of toggleClass() if you are just looking forward to hide or show the element,But if you are thinking of creating many elements with "show" or "hide" classes you will need to add additional css code to just hide the elements...so toggle() is better